# How process and thread related to virtual memory

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

I'm new to Linux and computer architecture, just some questions on how process and thread related to virtual memory and physical memory RAM.Below is my questions.

Q1-When there is two processes(process A and process B) running concurrently, if process A is running now, the process B's states like register values, heap objects etc have to be pushed to store on disk (Virtual Memory), and when the next context switch happens, process B will be "recovery" from disk to RAM, process A's state will be pushed to disk, is my understanding correct?

Q2- If my understanding in Q1 is correct, why not just save all processes on RAM too? normally we have large RAM like 16gb,32gb etc, how about just store every process's state on RAM, and when there is too many processes and RAM is going to run out, then further processes' states will be stored to disk?

Q3-How about threads? if there is multiple threads (e.g thread A and thread B), when thread A is running, does thread B's state will be pushed to stored on disk too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is my understanding correct?

No, it's wrong. Waiting or blocked processes don't get swapped to disc. They wait in memory. Virtual memory is not on disc.

Also on a system with two processors, two processes are running concurrently, so both processes A and B can be running at the same time.

> why not just save all processes on RAM too?

This is exactly what happens. All processes memory kindly waits in RAM until scheduler switches to this process.

Side note: If there is no RAM available and the system has swap available and this process is idle for some defined time, than it may get swapped on disc, ie. the processes memory may get moved to disc. But this doesn't happen immediately, it happens after a long time and in certain situation

> will be pushed to stored on disk too?

No.

Virtual memory is not about physical location of the memory. It's the other way round - virtual memory is a of abstraction that allows system to modify the physical (maybe if any) location of the memory. A simplest explanation I give: there is a special cpu register that is added to each address upon dereferencing. A user space program does `*(int*)4` but he doesn't get the value behind 4th byte in RAM, the special cpu register value is added to the pointer value upon dereferencing. The register value is configured by the system, can be different in different programs. So you can have exact same pointer values in two programs, but they both point to different locations. Of cause, this is over-over-simplification.

Comment: Curk Thanks for your answer. So does it mean that the large RAM we have, the less chance processes get swapped to hard disk?

Comment: and for threads, if there is only single core on a machine, and RAM run out, thread state will also get swapped to disk?

Comment: `that the large RAM we have, the less chance processes get swapped to hard disk?` - the less chance that RAM will fill up and then processes willl get swapped to disc. But no, not really. If you have tons of ram free and kernel sees that a process is never run, it usually swaps it anyway. There is also swappiness sys setting.